# "Constant thrust" engine vs "constant power" engine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, aircraft

I read that a piston engine, under maximum fuel intake, provides constant power, while the thrust depends on velocity, while a jet engine is the opposite - provides constant thrust, with the power depending on velocity.

I'm trying to wrap my head around this. I understand that with the piston engine, what gets created is rotational momentum which is then converted to thrust by the propeller, and I guess I sort of see, very vaguely, how the speed of air rushing by makes the propeller more/less efficient at generating thrust (though I don't think I *really* understand this).

But somehow it still seems strange. After all, in both engines there's a chemical reaction that makes gas rapidly expand and push at things, right? If that's the case, why isn't it fundamentally about thrust - the momentum of the rushing gas - in both cases?

I think my understanding of thrust/power and their grounding in momentum/energy is not solid enough. Would appreciate some physics-minded explanation that breaks this down to the underlying movement of particles/bodies and their momenta/energies as much as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the power of a car limited?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632132/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124135/discussion-on-question-by-anatolyvorobey-constant-thrust-engine-vs-constant-p).